# Do I need to "free" memory after dynamically remove table rows with images from an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-management, browser

In my web application I dynamically add images into a table, one `tr` row for each image. Based on the images on the server I also dynamically remove old images from the table again. That logic works fine.

I add new images to the top of the table `images_tab` like this:

```js
$("#images_tab > tbody").prepend(createImageTableRow(newImageFileName));

function createImageTableRow(fileName) {
    return $("<tr>").append($("<td>").append($("<img>")
        .attr("src", "/static/images/" + fileName)
        .css("width", "100%")
    ))
}
```

And to remove an image / row from the bottom of the table again I do this:

```js
$('#images_tab tr:last').remove();
```

Now I am wondering: Do I need to keep an eye on the browsers memory consumption when dynamically adding and removing images to/from the page? Or is it sufficient to call `$(...).remove()` as shown above and the browser takes care of all memory management?

Comment: As with almost all performance considerations, the best advice is "measure it". Run the application, removing the rows. Keep track of memory usage (most browsers' developer tools have utilities for this). Make sure to leave time for the garbage collector to run if necessary. See if there's a memory leak.